# Set button as selected state and change style

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, visualstatemanager

This is my actual button style:

```
<Style x:Key="CategoryButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Path x:Name="TabPath" StrokeThickness="2"
                          Margin="{Binding ElementName=buttonContent, Converter={x:Static c:ContentToMarginConverter.Value}}"
                          Stroke="{StaticResource BorderBrush1}"
                          Fill="{StaticResource TabItemPathBrush}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="1,0" 
                                            Segments="{Binding ElementName=buttonContent, Converter={x:Static c:ContentToPathConverter.Value}}">
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.LayoutTransform>
                            <!-- For some reason  -->
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                        </Path.LayoutTransform>
                    </Path>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="TabItemTopBorder" Height="2" Visibility="Visible"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="{StaticResource BorderBrush1}"
                               Margin="{Binding ElementName=TabPath, Path=Margin}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="buttonContent" Margin="10,2,10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      TextElement.Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="TabPath">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFe4f6fa"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect Direction="302" Opacity="0.4" 
                                                        ShadowDepth="2" Softness="0.5"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and I need add code that I could set button to selected state which looks like when button is pressed. I was thinking about using VisualStateManager but I am not sure if it's good way and how can I do this. I've started with something like this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
     <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TabPath" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFe4f6fa" />
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
     </VisualState>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

But It's not working. I just don't know what to use in storyboard.

**Edit** - Almost working:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
     <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabPath" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#FFe4f6fa" Duration="0:0:0" />
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabPath" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#FFa9cde7" Duration="0:0:0" />               
      </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
```

Forget to add my brushes:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectedPathBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFe4f6fa" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFa9cde7" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemPathBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFa9cde7" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3164a5" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. There is no `Selected` visual state for button, You could use a `ToggleButton` if you want to show a Checked state. Or by `Selected`, do you mean `Focused` state?

Comment: I mean that I can define some state and then change visual to this stat by something like this: `var bl = VisualStateManager.GoToState(selectedButton, "Activate", true);`. It really not depends on name of state (Selected, Activate, it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VisualStates` should be declared on the root element of the `ControlTemplate`. With the following code,

```
        <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FillBrush" Color="Magenta" />
        <Color x:Key="StateBrush" >#a3bfb1</Color>
        <Style x:Key="CategoryButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>

            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="Green" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" x:Name="root">

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TabPath" 
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="{StaticResource StateBrush}">

                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                                <Path x:Name="TabPath" StrokeThickness="1" 

                      Stroke="Blue"
                      Fill="{StaticResource FillBrush}" Canvas.Left="16.75"
          Canvas.Top="14"
          Width="50"
          Height="40"
          Data="F1 M 26.75,24L 16.75,34L 23.5,34L 34,24L 23.5,14L 16.75,14L 26.75,24 Z ">
                                    <Path.LayoutTransform>
                                        <!-- For some reason  -->
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                                    </Path.LayoutTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="buttonContent" Margin="10,2,10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button x:Name="test" Style="{StaticResource CategoryButtonStyle}" Content="Test"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200px" BorderBrush="#888" BorderThickness="1px"/>
</Grid>
```

this code will change the state as intended.

> VisualStateManager.GoToState(test, "TestState", true);

Make changes to the template as required, but make sure you put the VisualState declaration in the Root element of the `ControlTemplate` (`Border` in this example)

**EDIT**:
I've updated the Selected `VisualState`'s transition declaration with correct property path. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: This TestState is working but I can't get to work state which changes property Fill in Path.

Comment: @Bibo, The path and value should be specified as per my edit. Check if it resolves the problem.

Comment: thanks but I want to use that converters because it resize paths of the buttons accord to lenght of button content. Have you any solution that works with path like I haven in my question?

Comment: Ignore the `Path`'s code, Just take note of `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"` in the `VisualState` Transition, You can use your existing Markup of the Path. I just removed them for testing as I don't have the code for them. it should work fine as Converter is not for `Fill`.

Comment: @Bibo Can you update the error you get with the converters in place, if any?

Comment: There isn't any error. It just don't change color. I started with your code which works and I changed it to mine so I found where is problem. The problem is with `Fill` and that I use `StaticResources`. If I use just color then when changing state the color is changed too but when I have there `StaticResource` than it still same. Do you know solution for this? And one more problem. When I move with mouse out of button then the state is changed back to `Normal` state. Can I made it permanent until I change it to `Normal` state?

Comment: @Bibo See my updated code. I'm not sure where you have the problem. it works as expected. Remove unwanted `VisualState` declarations to prevent button from automatically changing states. For better control, you'll need to derive your own control.

Comment: I edited my post and I forget to show my brushes in resources. There are LinearGradient so that's why I have problem. Now I have that ColorAnimation and it's working but I have another problem. Now when I change state of one button it will change colors of all buttons. So what's wrong now? Why the buttons are changing? Maybe I still do this wrong way? How can I change LinearGradientBrush in button from one to another?

Comment: :) That is because you are changing the color of the same brush which is shared by all the buttons. Move the brushes to `ControlTemplate.Resources` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I just give the bounty to wrong answer :/ You helped me very much, thank you and sorry.

Comment: :) no problem about that. Accept the helpful answer so other users can spend less time finding solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ToggleButton` that uses the same style and template.

In your style (the one in your original question) change `TargetType` on style and control template to `ButtonBase`.

In control template triggers add this trigger:

```
 <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="TabPath">
         <Setter.Value>
             <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFe4f6fa"/>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
     <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
         <Setter.Value>
             <DropShadowBitmapEffect Direction="302" Opacity="0.4" ShadowDepth="2" Softness="0.5"/>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Trigger>
```

Now you can use this style for buttons, toggle buttons, radio buttons and check boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use Blend for such task, it's really the companion to Visual Studio for developing WPF applications.

In a few clicks you would get to it, nothing prevents you to either use it or just copy the XAML it generated to your project.

*Editing the button style*

[image]

*Triggers*

[image]

*Here are all your button states*

[image]

Blend is like bread for butter, WPF is tastier with it, unless you prefer plain butter :-)

Note that if you are on VS2012 and working on a WPF project, [Microsoft Blend + SketchFlow Preview for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/jj154135.aspx) is the version that will allow you to edit WPF projects. The version bundled with VS2012 is only for Windows Store apps.